# Testing flask_sockets app

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest, flask-sockets

I am building an app using [flask_sockets](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sockets) library. How do I test it?

Here is a code sample I want to write unit tests for:

```
import flask
from flask import Flask
from flask_sockets import Sockets

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

ws_conns = []


@sockets.route('/echo')
def echo_socket(ws):
    #on connect
    ws_conns.append(ws)

    #while connected
    while True:
        # message = ws.receive()
        # if message is None:
        # #socket has closed/errored
        #     break
        for c in ws_conns:
            c.send('hello and goodbye!')

    #disconnected
    ws_conns.remove(ws)
    ws.close()
```

I have using this code from [this git repo](https://github.com/whichlight/flask-websockets-test).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am just looking into this myself.